# Doesn't Entity Framework support protected navigation properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have declared an entity like this (the actual class obviously also has an ID property, mapping is done etc., but it is not the issue, so I have skipped it here):

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children {get; set;}
}
```

This works perfect:

```
public class Consumer
{
    void DoBusiness()
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var entity = ctx.Parents.Find(keyOfParent);
            // This is as expected: entity.Children refers to a collection which 
            // Entity Framework has assigned, a collection which supports lazy loading.
        }
    }
}
```

Now I change the visibility of the Children collection to be protected:

```
public class Parent
{
    protected virtual ICollection<Child> Children {get; set;}
}
```

This brings an unexpected result:

```
public class Consumer
{
    void DoBusiness()
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var entity = ctx.Parents.Find(keyOfParent);
            // This is NOT as expected: entity.Children is null. I would expect, that it 
            // had been referring to a collection which Entity Framework would have been 
            // assigning, a collection which should support lazy loading.
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, if I in the situation, where Children is protected try to explicitly load the children via:

```
ctc.Entry(entity).Collection(x => x.Children)
```

Then I get this exception:

> The property "Children" on type 'Parent" is not a navigation property. The Reference and Collection methods can only be used with navigation properties. Use the Property or ComplexProperty method.

Therefore: What should I precisely do in order to have a protected navigation property using Entity Framework?

Comment: Why on the Earth would you like to do that? "Entities" in EF are no more than object representation of a database tables, records and relationships. They are not supposed to contain business logic. Therefore they and their members should be visible in order to be used in queries. The sample code `ctc.Entry(entity).Collection(x => x.Children)` could only be run from inside `Parent` class which is against these principles.

Comment: Because the concrete properties, which correspond to Children in the example, are solely going to be used via reflection and as a consequence the basic considerations you give concerning queries do not apply. Concerning your coding comment: Yes, obviously, but it underscores that Entity Framework does not treat the property as a navigation property after it has been made protected. Do you also have some contributing information, please?

Comment: If the property is marked `protected` how is the framework going to use that property and load it? It can't "see" it; only the child classes can.

Comment: By actually implementing it like shown here: https://owencraig.com/mapping-but-not-exposing-icollections-in-entity-framework/. My Children collection just remains null as I load a Parent and this is what I find odd. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: The link is broken, could you repost it? Speaking constructively, I've tried setting up such model and `Children` and was able to get it both lazy and explicit loaded. Do you have a reverse navigation property like `Parent Parent { get; set; }` in `Child` class? protected as well?

Comment: Yes, I also have a reverse navigation property. Are you able to paste all the code you have, if you have made such a small example, I will be really grateful. I try to paste the link again: https://owencraig.com/mapping-but-not-exposing-icollections-in-entity-framework/

Comment: Ha, looks like I did exactly the same trick as the guy from the link.

Comment: If you Find(keyOfParent) a parent, what is the value of its Children property then, isn't it null?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I've made it work.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    internal ICollection<Child> children;
    protected virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get { return children; } set { children = value; } }
    internal ICollection<Child> GetChildren() => Children;
    internal static Expression<Func<Parent, ICollection<Child>>> ChildrenSelector => p => p.Children;
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    internal Parent parent;
    protected virtual Parent Parent { get { return parent; } set { parent = value; } }
    internal Parent GetParent() => Parent;
    internal static Expression<Func<Child, Parent>> ParentSelector => c => c.Parent;
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
            .HasMany(Parent.ChildrenSelector)
            .WithRequired(Child.ParentSelector)
            .Map(a => a.MapKey("ParentId"));

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

The explicit fields used are not essential - I've put them in order to be able to watch what's in there, you can continue using auto properties.

The essential part is providing property accessor expressions and using them with Fluent API configuration. Without an explicit configuration, you get the behavior you are describing. With it, everything works.

For instance, lazy loading:

```
var parent = ctx.Parents.Find(keyOfParent);
var children = parent.GetChildren();
```

or explicit loading:

```
var parent = ctx.Parents.Find(keyOfParent);
db.Entry(parent).Collection("Children").Load();
var children = parent.children;
```

**UPDATE:** Quite weird, if we replace the configuration code

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
    .HasMany(Parent.ChildrenSelector)
    .WithRequired(Child.ParentSelector)
    .Map(a => a.MapKey("ParentId"));
```

with the fully equivalent by definition

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
    .HasRequired(Child.ParentSelector)
    .WithMany(Parent.ChildrenSelector)
    .Map(a => a.MapKey("ParentId"));
```

database tables and FKs are the same, but the loading does not work! So either the working solution is accidentally hitting a backdoor, or there is a bug in EF. In both cases, the feature seems problematic to me and I would simply use `public` accessors in order to avoid surprises.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ivan. It is really very nice and constructive of you! Can't you change the definition of the model a bit, i.e. replace yours with: modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasRequired(Child.ParentSelector).WithMany(Parent.ChildrenSelector).Map(a => a.MapKey("ParentId")); and see if the proxy stuff still works? Shouldn't these two approaches be redundant to each other? Is there actually a reason why you have used Map and not HasForeignKey?

Comment: `HasForeignKey` is when you have an explicit field in the model. e.g. if the `Child` class has `public int ParentId { get; set; }` then you will use `HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId)`. While `MapKey` is used when you don't have such explicit field and just to specify the table column name for the field. It's optional, if you don't include that, you'll get by default "Parent_Id". The configuration is very important and is different depending of what fields do you include explicitly in the entity classes.

Comment: The proper configuration is crucial to make the solution working. Initially I didn't include configuration and was getting exactly the same behavior as you are explaining in the post.

Comment: Yes, but actually you had an explicit Id field in Child but used Map and not HasForeignKey, which made me to wonder. Can't you try to configure the mapping as I suggested in my previous comment, i.e. to configure mapping from Child and not from Parent, because here it actually doesn't work to me? This I find strange as I would consider the two approaches to be equivalent or have I overlooked something? Do you know if even both mappings should be present?

Comment: `modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasRequired(Child.ParentSelector).WithMany(Parent.C‌​hildrenSelector).Map(a => a.MapKey("ParentId"));` also works because it's equivalent of the one I used. When you configure association, you use either one or the other way. No need to have them both.

Comment: I don't have explicit **ParentId** field. Id is PK, here we are talking about FK.

Comment: Concerning "Id is PK, here we are talking about FK": Yes, it's obvious, please excuse me. Have you actually tried with modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasRequired(Child.ParentSelector).WithMany(Parent.‌​C‌​hildrenSelector).Map(a => a.MapKey("ParentId")); and seen that it works? The reason why I pick at this is, that this is actually the difference between may approach, which didn't work, and yours which works.

Comment: You are bloody right!!! It makes no any sense to me, but with my way it works, and with your totally equivalent way it doesn't!  I have absolutely no idea why.

Comment: Thank you very much spending the time to verify it as well. In fact I find it quite peculiar that it is at all possible to achieve such a difference. I could be skeptical that an invariant in the model inside Entity Framework is not valid when using the non-working configuration. Unless there is something we don't think of, I would assume it should not be possible to bring the internal model of Entity Framework to a state, where the non-working behavior is a consequence. The inverse is not the case, that your approach for mapping would cause the Parent property of Child to be null.

Comment: What is interesting (and also weird) though is that configuration starting from `Parent` seem to work in all scenarios - lazy and explicit, initiated by Parent or Child. And Parent property of Child is always correct. Anyway, you are welcome, it was interesting to me too to check this cases and fill my "knowledge base" with something new :)

Comment: I have now reported it to Microsoft: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2942